# Why is $\sum (y_{i})^{2}=y^{T}y$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics

This is the formula for Syy in my lecture notes:

$Syy=\sum (y_{i}-\bar y)^{2}=\sum (y_{i})^{2}-n \bar y^{2}=y^{T}y-n \bar y^{2}$

Why is $\sum (y_{i})^{2}=y^{T}y$ ?

How to change the first notation to the matrix notation on the right?

Comment: Start with $y=(y_1, ..., y_n)$, and write out $y^Ty=(y_1..., y_n)^T(y_1, ..., y_n)$ and see what pops out

Comment: Using the definition $y=\begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\\vdots\\y_n\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $y$ is a column vector with entries $y_1, y_2, \ldots, y_n$,

\begin{align*}
y^T y &= \pmatrix{y_1 & y_2 & \ldots & y_n} \pmatrix{y_1\cr y_2\cr \vdots \cr y_n}  \\
    &= y_1^2 + y_2^2 + \cdots + y_n^2  \\
    &= \sum_{i=1}^n y_i^2
\end{align*}